# Thriller novel which opens with an amnesiac child in bloodsoaked shoes emerging from a forest

Tags: identification-request

I only read the first chapter or so of this book (someone else in my cast was reading it, and let me borrow it for a bit) but it stuck in my head. It was around 2008-2010 in New Jersey (possibly between June and August of 2008 if my memory is right that I was in a production of *The Pajama Game* at the time). It was a hardback book, I think with a mostly white cover. The chapter I read opened with a stunned child (I think adolescent rather than a toddler or teenager) stumbling out of a forest with their shoes so filled with blood that their sodden socks were squelching within the shoes. I think it was a first-person recounting from the point of view of the child, with them being unable to recall what exactly had happened to them that left them in that state. I don't believe that they themselves were hurt, and my brain is fuzzy on whether there's any proof of anyone else having been killed or hurt that would account for the blood when they were found. I think that the blurb indicated that, after that first chapter, it was about the protagonist, now an adult, still trying to solve the mystery of what happened to them and how they escaped.

My brain is honestly split between whether they were a "sole survivor" of something, or if it was simply unexplained at the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This reminds me of "[In the woods](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/237209.In_the_Woods)" by Tana French. It was published in 2007 which is consistent with the date you give. The opening chapter describes the search for a 12-year old boy in Dublin who has gone missing:

> At 10.20 p.m., a policeman with a torch found Adam Ryan in a densely
> wooded area near the centre of the wood, standing with his back and
> palms pressed against a large oak tree

Notable points about him were that he had lost his memory, and that his shoes were filled with blood:

> The shoes
> were heavily bloodstained, the socks less heavily. Later analysis of
> the staining patterns showed that the blood had soaked through the
> shoes from the inside outwards; it had soaked through the socks, in
> lesser concentrations, from the outside in.

The boy eventually becomes a policeman and works on the case of the murder and sexual assault of a child, and how his buried memories relate to this case.

One of the covers is indeed mostly white. I attach an image in case that jogs your memory.

[image: Cover of "In the woods" by Tana French]

The book is available free to read from the [Internet Library](https://archive.org/details/inwoods0000fren/page/8/mode/2up).

Comment: That does spark some memory. I've put a hold on a copy at my local library. I will let you know. Thank you.

Comment: @SeanDuggan It's available at the Internet library https://archive.org/details/inwoods0000fren/page/8/mode/2up if you want to look quickly

Comment: I think I've read up to where I was before, and it indeed seems like a match. :) Maybe I'll finish it this time.